# How to put batch command output in desired column of csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file, input, echo, multiple-columns

i'm new in batch programmation and it's been 8 hours i'm trying to figure how to resolve my problem. That's why i'm here, i'm sure I passed out of something ...

I have a command

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Demarre le %date:~0,8% a %time:~0,5% >> C:\TEMP\pointage.csv
```

which put in **pointage.csv** the date on PC start up (we will call it **A**)

I have another command

```
@Echo Off&SetLocal
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-4" %%A In (
    `Powershell "$OS=GWmi Win32_OperatingSystem;$UP=(Get-Date)-"^
    "($OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LastBootUpTime));$DO='d='+$UP.Days+"^
    "' h='+$UP.Hours+' n='+$UP.Minutes;Echo $DO"`) Do (
    Set "%%A"&Set "%%B"&Set "%%C")
Echo Temps de fonctionnement: %d% jour, %h% heures, %n% minutes >> C:\TEMP\pointage.csv
Echo Eteint le %date:~0,8% a %time:~0,5% >> C:\TEMP\pointage.csv
```

which put in **pointage.csv** the date when PC is shutdown (call **B**) + the time that pass between launch and shutdown (call **C**)

The problem is :

**A**, **B** & **C** are located in A1 for **A**, A2 for **B**, A3 for **C** in my **pointage.csv**

I want to put :

- Every **A** results on column A,
- Every **B** results on column B,
- Every **C** results on column C.

in my **pointage.csv**

How to do that ? I tried many things, for example creating 3 files.txt and put them A,B & C then trying to use for /F function. But I don't find anything which works a little bit.

Thank you for helping !

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem, it's really simple ...

```
echo "hello";"stack";"overflow" >> pointage.csv
```

Worked

Here is my all code :

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%a in ('wmic os get lastbootuptime ^| find "."') do (
  set _datetime=%%a
  )
set _boottime=%_datetime:~6,2%-%_datetime:~4,2%-%_datetime:~0,4%%_datetime:~8,2%:%_datetime:~10,2%

For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-4" %%A In (
    `Powershell "$OS=GWmi Win32_OperatingSystem;$UP=(Get-Date)-"^
    "($OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LastBootUpTime));$DO='d='+$UP.Days+"^
    "' h='+$UP.Hours+' n='+$UP.Minutes;Echo $DO"`) Do (
        Set "%%A"&Set "%%B"&Set "%%C"
)

Echo "%_boottime%";"%date:~0,8% %time:~0,5%";"%d% days, %h% hours, %n% minutes" >> C:\TEMP\pointage.csv
    
endlocal
```